# tortoise tree conflict is in local or on the server?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

during the merge from **one branch** to **another branch**, there are few **tree conflict**. I cancelled the merge, and **revert** all other changes. but the tree conflicts are still here. I am thinking delete my local copy and check out that branch again. does that will get a new fresh copy **without any tree conflicts**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer: yes :)
Only a commit or a branch/tag operation from your workingcopy, change something on the server.